# Swift: While loop doesn't exit when results from API sets condition to false

Tags: swift

I am attempting to fetch a set of data from an API until there are no more results returning from the API. I wrap this inside a while loop and intend to exit the while loop when the condition is set to false. I do this by checking if the count of the returned result is 0.

However, my implementation doesn't exit even though the condition has been set to false.

Code:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serial")
var skip = 0
var continueFetch = true
var allObjects = [MyObject]()

while continueFetch == true {
    group.enter()
    serialQueue.async {
        semaphore.wait()
        
        APIClient.shared.getObjects(skip: skip) { results in
            switch results {
                case .success(let returnedObjects):                            
                    if let objects = returnedObjects.objects {
                        allObjects += objects
                        skip += 500
                        continueFetch = objects.count != 0
                        print(objects.count != 0, continueFetch) 
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Err", error.localizedDescription)
            }
                
            semaphore.signal()
            group.leave()
        }                
    }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("Count", allObjects.count) <== never reaches here
}
```

When `continueFetch` is set to false, the API is still called and never exits. The final print line in the `group.notify` never gets called as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you describe how you want to this API to be called? Do you want to call it sequentially, each time after the previous time has returned a result, and until objects.count == 0?

Comment: Your code is rather confusing. Do you want to run all the API requests all in parallel (with a dispatch group) or one by one (with a semaphore)? Combining the two doesn't make much sense to me...

Comment: @Sweeper I want the API to be called sequentially, and each time checking the count of the objects. If 0, exit the loop, if not 0, continue to call sequentially till objects count is 0

Comment: Remove the dispatch group then, and put the entire while loop in `serialQueue.async`. Though this can be really done with the concurrency features in Swift 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what's happening here is that you have entered way too many tasks into the dispatch group. `group.enter` is called as quickly as the while loop can run. Note that the while loop doesn't wait at all - all the waiting is done on the serial queue. The while loop just keeps on entering tasks into the group, at a rate way faster than the API can respond.

Of course, you eventually stop entering tasks when `continueFetch` is set to false, but that's still way too many tasks. All of them needs to be processed sequentially before the closure passed to `notify` is called.

This is probably what you meant to write:

```
serialQueue.async {
    while continueFetch == true {
        semaphore.wait()
        APIClient.shared.getObjects(skip: skip) { results in
            switch results {
                case .success(let returnedObjects):
                    if let objects = returnedObjects.objects {
                        allObjects += objects
                        skip += 500
                        continueFetch = objects.count != 0
                        print(objects.count != 0, continueFetch)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Err", error.localizedDescription)
            }

            semaphore.signal()
        }
    }
    print("Count", allObjects.count)
}
```

Also, note that in Swift 5.5, you can do this much more elegantly with the [concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html) language features. Here is a rough idea of how it would look.

```
// async wrapper for getObjects
func getObjects(skip: Int) async throws -> [MyObject]? {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        getObjects(skip: skip) { results in
            continuation.resume(with: results.map(\.objects))
        }
    }
}

// ...

func getAllObjects() async -> [MyObject] {
    var skip = 0
    var continueFetch = true
    var allObjects = [MyObject]()
    while continueFetch {
        do {
            if let objects = try await getObjects(skip: skip) {
                allObjects += objects
                skip += 500
                continueFetch = objects.count != 0
                print(objects.count != 0, continueFetch)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Err", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    print("Count", allObjects.count)
    return allObjects
}
```